# WP Excerpt - Line Break at Excerpt Problem

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to add line break in WP Excerpt?

```
    I tried to make <br> inside the excerpt but not working.. 
    I tried to make <br /> inside the excerpt but not working too.. 
    Even i've tried to make <li> inside the excerpt but not working as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the follows to print your excerpt -

```
$your_excerpt = 'Your excerpt goes here';
$your_excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_content', $your_excerpt );
$your_excerpt = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $your_excerpt );
echo $your_excerpt;
```